No webpack folders when running npm init electron-app@latest testApp -- --template=webpack
When i run npm init electron-app@latest testApp -- --template=webpack, to create an electron application, it doesnt create any webpack folders.
I am following along with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pnsaQs45Kj8&t=142s
When they run this command, they instantly get the webpack folders but i do not.
I tried installing webpack manually, as well as webpack cli, but nothing is making those files appear.

Try use:
npx create-electron-app my-new-app -- —-template=webpack

